# Добавить "корректирующий" элемент в шапку

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, header

Есть шапка сайта и его логотип, хотелось бы убрать кусочек `border`'а, чтобы была полностью серая внутренняя заливка.

[image: Шапка]

Красный прямоугольник - наглядная "заплатка" (сделана `div`ом).

Есть ли какие-то более традиционные методы решения проблемы?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: блок с надписью home сделать выше не вариант?

Comment: @Duoxx в каком смысле?

Comment: Добавьте код, ничего не понятно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так?

```css
.menu-block {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.logo {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #888;
  border: 5px solid #333;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.menu {
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
  height: 60px;
  background: #888;
  border: 5px solid #333;
  border-left: 0; /* Убираем бордер с левой части */
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0; /* Убираем скругление углов с левой части */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  left: 75px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-block">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="menu"></div>
</div>
```